# Sidebar disappears in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, sidebar

In IE8 the sidebar disappears. Same in IE7. Any thoughts on how to bring the sidebar back?

http://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/f28f91bf169e4cc94377c50d5ef081b6dfad35fe

http://thetrafficticketman.com/scott-markowitz/

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer sadly does not support much of CSS and HTML and js... In other words it's just a very broken browser that needs to be updated. You cant fix it unless you specially create new scripts/CSS to work with only internet explorer users.

Although this may not be as big of a problem because: many people just don't use internet explorer anymore..

Comment: Agreed. Just don't even bother supporting IE. Maybe throw up a warning if you see someone using IE. Maybe.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Unfortunately, 15.6% of browsing North America uses IE8, including my client.  http://royal.pingdom.com/2012/04/23/current-status-of-the-browser-wars/